# hibernate bean validation - group validation sequence

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I cannot get my GroupSequence to work. I want the inner constraint's on the `id` property to validate first before the unique constraint's are validated.

In each interface

**Entity**

```
@UniqueNaturalId(groups = {Create.class, Update.class})
public abstract Entity
{
    @Null(groups = {PreCreate.class})
    @NotNull(groups = {PreUpdate.class, PreDelete.class })
    private Integer id;

    // other properties without groups
}
```

**Group interfaces**

```
@GroupSequence({PreUpdate.class, Update.class})
public interface PreUpdate {}

// PreCreate and PreDelete follow same structure
```

**Calling groups for update operation**

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update">
    javax.validation.groups.Default, 
    package.PreUpdate
</property>
```

**Environment**

Glassfish 3.1.2 with built-in Hibernate-Validator 4.2.

Comment: The config look ok so far. What is your environment? How do you use JPA? What is your JPA provider and which version of Hibernate Validator are you using? Is there something in the log files? Have you tried turning on debug logging?

Comment: I am using glassfish 3.1.2 with built-in hibernate validator 4.2. I am just using default hibernate core. Have to check tomorrow what my jpa provider is and about the logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@GroupSequence({PreUpdate.class, Update.class})
public interface PreUpdate {}
```

This interface declaration will result in a cyclic Group validation.

Creating a new group including the ordered sequence of validation groups:

```
@GroupSequence({Default.class, PreUpdate.class, Update.class})
public interface UpdateOrdered {}
```

and replacing the groups in the hibernate configuration with the new group like following:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update">
        package.UpdateOrdered
</property>
```

Results now in the correct sequence of validation.

*In this example `@UniqueNaturalId` is validated after the inner constraints on the `id` property.*